# Steam won't download - thinks I have less free space than I do

Tags: steam, technical-issues, pc

When downloading Rainbow Six: Siege on Steam, it gives me the error "Not enough disk space..." 

I tried reinstalling again, but when it reaches 90%, it shows me that error message again, even though I have 120GB free space on my disk drive.

PS : when right-clicking on the game library, and then going to *Properties*/*Browse local files*, it redirects me to the the Rainbow Six: Siege game directory, which is empty. If I search the location of the downloaded files during the download, I find that all the downloaded files go to `Program Files (86x)/Steam/SteamApps/Downloading`

I have already tried:

- Verifying Integrity of game files;
- clearing the download cache;
- repairing the directory folder;
- and reinstalling steam.

What could be the cause for this?

Comment: Do you have a different drive you could try installing it on?

Comment: @Nassir When you say "More than 30GB free" in your question, it suggests you don't have *much more* than 30GB.  32-35GB maybe.  If you *actually* have 120GB free (per comments on the answer, below), this will clearly impact the quality of answers you receive. Please update your question with as many details as you can about what you've already done.  Be as specific as you can, so we don't waste your time suggesting things you've already checked/tried.

Comment: @Steve-O i make some edits in the question, thanks!

Comment: @Joachim nope i have :D which is have 50 GB, so i have 120GB free on the C: btw i was downloading the game and it goes well but this time, didn't :(

Comment: Steam always downloads to its `downloading` folder, before moving everything to the game folder. Are you using Windows 10? Is it an HDD or an SSD you're downloading on? For now, I recommend running Windows' *Disk Clean-up*, which can be found by searching in the Start menu. My guess is that lots of files are flagged for removal, but not actually removed.

Comment: @Joachim ah okey i got you! im using win7 with an SSD ! i already tried to clean my disk : C:/right click properties/clean disk and i launched the download again through steam, for now it gets 60% hopefully it wouldn't stop...

Comment: You need to show a screenshot of how you determine you have 120 GB free.

Comment: Deleted the answer i provided, as you've changed the question.

Comment: @Nelson Its fixed tho i will add the fix in the command section!

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the Download directory in `Program Files (x86)/Steam/SteamApps`, then go to settings in Steam, and repair your download directory. 

Restart steam and restart the download, so you have to wait until it finishes, and it will work.

[image: Steam screenshot]

Comment: I edited in an image of the relevant Steam settings for easier navigation.

Comment: The pictures show how to add a new Steam Library Folder, not how to clear and repair your download cache